# smoothScrollToPosition is flickering on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView with a list of items that I want to scroll to when the certain event happens. I am using `smoothScrollToPosition` but to my surprise, it is not only not smooth at all, but also I get a flicker effect like it has to restore a base position before actually scrolling. The effect can be seen here:

[http://i.imgur.com/rrpLr7N.mp4](https://i.imgur.com/rrpLr7N.mp4)

Is this normal behavior?

Adapter code:

```
@ActivityScope
class HighlightListAdapter @Inject constructor() : RecyclerView.Adapter<HighlightListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

private var highlights: List<Highlight> = emptyList()
private var itemClick: ((Highlight, Int) -> Unit)? = null

private var selectedRow: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val binding = holder.binding
    val highlight = highlights[position]
    var viewModel = binding.viewModel

    viewModel?.unbind()

    viewModel = HighlightViewModel(highlight)
    binding.viewModel = viewModel
    viewModel.bind()

    if(selectedRow.contains(position)) {
        binding.rootItemView.alpha = 1.0f
    }
    else {
        binding.rootItemView.alpha = 0.5f
    }

    holder.setClickListener(itemClick)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = highlights.size

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ItemHighlightListBinding>(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            R.layout.item_highlight_list,
            parent,
            false
    )
    return ViewHolder(binding)
}

fun updateEvents(highlights: List<Highlight>) {
    this.highlights = highlights
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}


fun setClickListener(itemClick: ((Highlight, Int) -> Unit)?) {
    this.itemClick = itemClick
}


fun enableRow(index: Int) {
    //Clear previous selection (only if we want single selection)
    selectedRow.clear()
    //Select specified row
    selectedRow.add(index)
    //Let the adapter redraw
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

class ViewHolder(val binding: ItemHighlightListBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun setClickListener(callback: ((Highlight, Int) -> Unit)?) {
        binding.viewModel.clicks().subscribe {
            callback?.invoke(binding.viewModel.highlight, adapterPosition)
        }
    }

}

fun getSelected() = selectedRow

}
```

layout file:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="tv.mycujoo.mycujooplayer.ui.video.highlights.HighlightViewModel" />
</data>



 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                  android:id="@+id/root_item_view"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:alpha="0.5"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:clickable="true"
                  android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onClick()}"
                  android:background="@color/dark_black"
                  android:padding="@dimen/single_padding"
                  >


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@{viewModel.time}"
            android:textColor="@color/light_gray"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/single_padding"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            tools:text="122''"/>

        <ImageView
            android:background="@drawable/bg_circle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/single_padding"
            android:padding="@dimen/single_padding"
            tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            app:imageResource="@{viewModel.image}"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:textColor="@color/light_gray"
                tools:text="@{viewModel.name}"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/light_gray"
                tools:text="@{viewModel.team}"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <ImageView
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:src="@drawable/tv_avatar_default"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: post some code..

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: done, not sure it helps though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem lies in enable row  notifyDataSetChanged().It refreshes the entire dataset which results in flicking of the list.Try this

```
fun enableRow(index: Int) {
//Clear previous selection (only if we want single selection)
selectedRow.clear()
//Select specified row
selectedRow.add(index)
//Let the adapter redraw
notifyItemRangeChanged(index,highlights.size())
}
```

Comment: Alright this seems to fix it somehow but the problem is I do need to update all rows, since I want only one row to be selected (selecting means UI is different for the selected row)

Comment: I dint get you clearly,but if you felt this helped you please upvote the answer.Again  notifyDataSetChanged() and notifyItemRangeChanged() is pretty much same which refreshes the data list

Comment: What I mean is, the selected item from the list shows up in a different color. So every time a new event is selected (and scrolled to) the other items need to be refreshed so they show up as unselected. If I do what you say, I am only refreshing a range of items starting from the selected one, resulting in previously selected items to remain selected.

Comment: Have you heard of sparse boolean array?maintain a boolean array.Whenever you click a position store that position as true in boolean array,and check the position of bind holder with the posiition in the array.

Comment: nevermind, got it working, thanks @Anonymous for finding the issue